# Crazy 8s rules question

Tags: crazy8s

I was recently playing a game of crazy. We had a dispute over the rules I said:

- A 2 means that you have to pick up two more cards
- A Jack means that you skip town

My friends disagree. So I was wondering if I was correct it was or not.

Comment: I recommend changing the title to something more specific, maybe "Canonical rules for crazy 8s?". An alternative would be to split this into two questions: "Does a 2 force you to draw 2 cards?" and "Does a Jack make you skip town?" or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found some [rules](http://www.pagat.com/eights/crazy8s.html). They agree on the 2, but disagree on the Jack.

The problem with these games, is that there are a lot of house rules. So there is a high probability that there are some differences in the rules.

The best way to avoid problems is to discuss and fix the rules before play. So you can focus on the fun part.